# Why need to then Mono.empty() in the default implementation of generated Open API Spring code?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, openapi-generator

Here is the default implementation of an API generated by the `openapi-generator-maven-plugin` using Spring Boot as library:

```
default Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>> testAPI(
    @Parameter(hidden = true) final ServerWebExchange exchange
) {
    Mono<Void> result = Mono.empty();
    exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
    return result.then(Mono.empty());
}
```

Being new to this, there are several things I don't understand:

1. There are two `Mono.empty()`, one being the result, one inside the `then(Mono.empty())`, why is it done like that?
2. Why can't it just returns one? e.g. `return Mono.empty();`
3. Or better yet, remove also the pass in `exchange` and just do:

```
return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED).build());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default implementation is more like a template that gives you a hint how to complete this API controller. For an API controller usually you need to create a response in at least two steps: first fetch data from some source and then make it a valid response. The template code can give you a start point to write such code. For example, I can write the following code using the template:

```java
public class UsersApiController implements UsersApi {
    @Override
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> usersGet(
            @Parameter(hidden = true) final ServerWebExchange exchange
    ) {
        var client = WebClient.create("http://calapi.inadiutorium.cz/");
        Mono<String> result = client.get().uri("/api/v0/en/calendars/general-en/today").retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class);
        return result.map(rep -> ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(rep));
    }
}
```

The first Mono.empty becomes the WebClient that gets data from another API, and the second Mono.empty is replaced by a map operation that transforms the API result to ResponseEntity object. If the generator only generates a Mono.empty, newcomers may feel difficult to start writing the controller.

Comment: OK, so the only reason is to leave some skeleton there? I guess its having some opposite effect in my case, its more confusing than being helpful there. Could simply leave some commented out code like what you have here, but simply return `Mono.just...`

Comment: @user1589188 OpenAPI generator does the same thing (generate sample code) for other supported languages. I agree that they can do it better for java/spring like adding more comments. This is a community driven project, so the quality of generator does depend on how many contributors work on the templeates.